# rhino mocks: how to build a fake socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, rhino-mocks

I tried to build a fake socket for testing using the following code:

```
var socket = MockRepository.GenerateStub<Socket>(
    AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP
);
socket.Stub(v => v.RemoteEndPoint).PropertyBehavior().Return(
    new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 12345)
);
```

However, the attempt to create the stub for the read only-property gives me the following exception:

> Invalid call, the last call has been used or no call has been made (make sure that you are calling a virtual (C#) / Overridable (VB) method).

Could anyone help me spot where it's going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thx Rup.

I solved it in the way that I wrote a wrapper class for Socket that exposed all needed methods as virtual.

```
public class SocketWrapper
{
    private readonly Socket _socket;

    public SocketWrapper(Socket socket)
    {
        _socket = socket;
    }

    public virtual EndPoint RemoteEndPoint
    {
        get { return _socket.RemoteEndPoint; }
    }

    public virtual void Close()
    {
        _socket.Close();
    }

    public virtual void EndDisconnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        _socket.EndDisconnect(asyncResult);
    }

    public virtual bool Connected
    {
        get { return _socket.Connected; }
    }

    public virtual int Send(byte[] data)
    {
        return _socket.Send(data);
    }

    public virtual IAsyncResult BeginReceive(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, SocketFlags flags, AsyncCallback callback, object state )
    {
        return _socket.BeginReceive(buffer, offset, size, flags, callback, state);
    }

    public virtual int EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResutl)
    {
        return _socket.EndReceive(asyncResutl);
    }

    public virtual IAsyncResult BeginDisconnect(bool reuseSocket,AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        return _socket.BeginDisconnect(reuseSocket, callback, state);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> where is my mistake?

The error message seems pretty self explanatory. You can only mock virtual methods. In your case you are trying to mock the getter of the [`RemoteEndPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.remoteendpoint.aspx) property but this property is not virtual => it is impossible to mock. Also it makes sense to create mocks for abstract class/interfaces. In your case you are trying to mock the Socket class which is impossible.